# $C^*$ -norm of direct sum of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A,B$ are $C^*$-algebras,the multiplication on $A\oplus B$ is defined as following:$(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1b_2),$my question is:how to define the norm on $A\oplus B$ such that $A\oplus B$ is a $C^*$ algebra.

I am still confused about the unitization of a $C^*$- algebra .When $A$ is non-unital ,$\tilde{A}$ is not isomporhic to $A\oplus \Bbb C$.The reason is: according to the multiplication mentioned above,if $\tilde{A}$ is isomporhic to $A\oplus \Bbb C$,then $A$ contains a unit,a contradiction.But if the mulpilication defined above ,how to define the norm of $A\oplus C$ such that it becomes a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: The unitization $\overline{A}$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is $A\oplus\mathbb{C}$ **only as a vector space**. The product is not the pointwise one, and the norm is not the product norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the product structure in your first paragraph, the norm on $A\oplus B$ given by
$$\|(a,b)\|=\max\{\|a\|,\|b\|\},$$
is a $C^*$-norm.

The reason that this does not work for the unitization $\tilde A$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is because of the following:  although we define $\tilde A$ to be $A\oplus\mathbb C$ as a vector space (moreover as a vector space with involution), the algebra structure on $\tilde A$ is given by
$$(a,\lambda)(b,\mu)=(ab+\mu a+\lambda b,\lambda\mu).$$
Hence the above norm may not (and does not) produce a $C^*$-norm on $\tilde A$.  Thus we need to be more clever when trying to norm $\tilde A$.

Comment: why can we define the multiplication on $\tilde{A}$ as following:$(a,\lambda)(b,\mu)=(ab,\lambda\mu)$?

Comment: As you state, when $A$ is non-unital, this multiplication would make $\tilde A$ non-unital.